# Instantiate prefabs in matrix shape UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, instantiation

My problem: I need to instantiate NxN prefabs to form a matrix on the screen.
My solution:

All the objects are instantiated and are set to have as parent a canvas. My prefab is anchored to the top-left corner to the canvas. My current solution that does not satisfy my need is:

```
int yAnchorPos = -100;
        for (int row = 0; row < nBoardSize; ++row)
        {
            int xAnchorPos = 100;
            _mGameBoard[row] = new GameObject[nBoardSize];
            for (int col = 0; col < nBoardSize; ++col)
            {
                _tilePrefab = Instantiate(_tilePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                _tilePrefab.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
                _tilePrefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector3(xAnchorPos,yAnchorPos,0);
                _tilePrefab.transform.tag = row.ToString() + col.ToString();
                _tilePrefab.transform.name = _tilePrefab.transform.tag;
                _mGameBoard[row][col] = _tilePrefab;
                _mGameBoard[row][col].GetComponent<Image>().color = colors[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 4)];
                xAnchorPos += 150;
            }
            yAnchorPos -= 150;
        }
```

But I would like my objects to have same distance between them even is I have to generate a matrix of 4x4, 6x6, 8x8, etc.
[image]
Is there any solution?

Comment: you just want them center instead of top left?

Comment: Yes, but I would like them to be in the center and resize to fit the screen. If I need to instantiate 4x4 the objects would be bigger in size so that the distance between them remain constant. If I need to instantiate 10x10 the squares should be smaller..

Answer (score 0):

psuedo code
measure total width of canvas
dedicate a percentage to spacing between elements
set element size as #of elements / (canvas width - spacing)
make a for loop in each iteration of i or j move the next ui element over or down by element size + (percent space / numelements)